# Is it a good idea to let App users access s3 objects using Temporary security credentials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am making a mobile app. When a user opens the app for the first time, the app will generate a long list of s3 objects. The user will retrieve a number of S3 objects every day. I am trying to figure out how to authenticate the users so that they can access the S3 objects.

I think presigned URLs is not a good option because the longest expiration duration is 7 days.

Is it a good idea to use temporary security credentials to authenticate users? I can create a REST API for the users to get temporary credentials, and whenever their credentials expire they can get a new one. One consideration is that, there can be potentially a large number of users, is it OK the generate a credential for each user?

Comment: This use case is what AWS Cognito is for: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html

Comment: Have you considered cognito, as already suggested?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding from your question there can be two scenarios, as mentioned below.

Scenario 1: User SSO (Single Sign On) is available
Scenario 2: User SSO is not available

Firstly, API is the good approach to provide S3 objects available for the user on app.

**Scenario 1:**
If there is user SSO for the app exists, then you do not need temporary security credentials to authenticate users. You just create API to fetch s3 object.

**Scenario 2:**
If there is no SSO for the app, then it is means you need set of general S3 objects, which are available for all the users, if this is the case then just do OAuth2.0/OpenID Connect authentication and provide the S3 object from API.